# no rule to process XMPPFramework module.modulemap

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp, warnings, xmppframework

I have integrated the xmppFramework pod for ios and I can't seem to get rid of this warning:

`warning: no rule to process file '/Users/Name/Documents/Workspace/Project-iOS/Project/Pods/XMPPFramework/module/module.modulemap' of type sourcecode.module-map for architecture arm64`

Comment: Any luck with your problem? I´m running into the same and opened this issue: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/683

Comment: Not yet, hopefully somebody will get back to you on github, good idea.